# How to carry an image across different files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Okay so I would really like to carry an image across from file B to file A. So when they upload an image (In Code 'B') using the upload button it displays into "Blah" and "Blah2" now what I need it to do is actually display in/where the code  `<img src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'compact' }}" alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}">` is (In Code 'B') and where it says `<img src="{{ item | img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ item.title | escape }}">` (In Code A) but I don't understand how to transfer the code over/call the code from "Code B" to "Code A"? Any suggestions and any help is extremely/unbelievably appreciated as I've been trying to figure this out for a week now and have got no where....... Thank you for even looking!

Code A:

```
<!-- Bold: Options 4-5 -->
{% if builder[0] %}
<img src="{{ builder[1] }}" alt="{{ builder[0] }}" /> 
{% else %}

                  <img src="{{ item | img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ item.title | escape }}">
                </a>


<!-- Bold: Options 4-6 -->
{% include 'boldoptions' with 'step6' %}
<!-- // end Options 4-6 -->

{% endif %}
 <!-- // end Options 4-5 -->
```

Code B:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <br>
    <img id="blah" src="" alt="Upload Image" />

     <img id="blah2" src="" alt="Upload Image" />

     <img id="grooved" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-6WXP99pR7HU/Vpa-nIDksdI/AAAAAAAAMkA/r59f0in-YyA/s800-Ic42/Grooved%252520View%252520For%252520Shopify.png" alt="your image" height="100" />
</form>

    <br/>
    <div id="noFileError" style="display:none;">
        <b>Please select a valid image file.</b>
    </div>
    <button id="checkimage" style="display:none;"> Check Image </button>
    <br/>
    <b>Resolution Check Result: </b>
  <p>If nothing is displayed underneath that means your image is top quality and ready for printing!</p>
    <p>

    </p>
    <div id="imageValidationError" style="display:none;">
        <b id="LR">Unfortunatley the image resolution is too low for our pixboards, you may still proceed with using the image but we cannot guarentee it will be a great resolution! By proceeding with this image you're agreeing and aknowladge that the resolution will not be to the high standards advertised.</b>
    </div>


  <style>

    #LR {
     color: red; 
    }

::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);

    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background-color: #555;
}

#blah {
 width:550px; 
  height:550px;
  background-image: url('path/to/image');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#blah2 {
 width:550px; 
  height:550px;
  background-image: url('path/to/image');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}

#grooved {
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  position: absolute;
  top: auto 0;
}
  </style>

  <script>
       function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                    isGoodImage(input.files[0])
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });


    function readURL2(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah2').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL2(this);
    });

    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function isSupportedBrowser() {
    return window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Image;
}

function getSelectedFile() {
    var fileInput = document.getElementById("imgInp");
    var fileIsSelected = fileInput && fileInput.files && fileInput.files[0];
    if (fileIsSelected)
        return fileInput.files[0];
    else
        return false;
}

function isGoodImage(file) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var image = new Image();

    image.onload = function() {
        // Check if image is bad/invalid
        if (this.width + this.height === 0) {
            this.onerror();
            return;
        }

        // Check the image resolution
        if (this.width >= 3000 && this.height >= 2000) {
            deferred.resolve(true);
        } else {
            $("#imageValidationError").show();
            deferred.resolve(false);
        }
    };

    image.onerror = function() {
        $("#noFileError").show();
        deferred.resolve(false);
    }

    image.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);

    return deferred.promise();
}

/** New Code **/
    $("#checkimage").click(function(){


      if (isSupportedBrowser()) {

          var file = getSelectedFile();
          if (!file) {
              $("#noFileError").show();
              return;
          }

          isGoodImage(file)
      }
    })
  </script>
```

---

```
<div class="product-single">
    <div class="grid product-single__hero">
      <div class="grid__item large--one-half">
        <div class="product-single__photos" id="ProductPhoto">
          {% assign featured_image = product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}
         <img src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" id="ProductPhotoImg"{% if settings.product_image_zoom_enable %} data-zoom="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %}>      
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Question doesn't make a lot of sense. Please scale all the html down to a minimal representation of the problem (far too much shown that isn't relevant) and define problem more clearly

Comment: @charlietfl shortened the code......

Comment: I need to transfer the image being displayed in the img id 'Blah' and 'Blah2' across to Code A where it says <img src="{{ item | img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ item.title | escape }}"> and also in Code B where it says: <img src="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}" alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" id="ProductPhotoImg"{% if settings.product_image_zoom_enable %} data-zoom="{{ featured_image | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %}>

Comment: @charlietfl Is that any better?

Comment: different page loads? or same page?

Comment: Code A is a different page and Code B is all one page.....

Comment: will need to store that url somewhere ... database,user  session, localStorage (for javascript use) etc.

Comment: url? and what if I don't have access to a  database etc.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that this is for a shop so the uploaded file will be by a customer and the images will be different every time..... @charlietfl

Comment: I don't know what use case for these pages is or if user is logged in or anonymous. If you want something created on one page to show on another you have to store some data somehwere. I gave you numerous options

Comment: @charlietfl okay so just looked into HTML localStorage but how would I set it up for images/ link it across files/pages?

Comment: you would need to use javascript to store and retrive the data and change the elements in the page

Comment: @charlietfl Just looked at this.... would i just link the Id instead of "last name" ? [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: where does all the other data used in page get stored? You have a page full of dynamic data...doesn't make sense there is no database

Comment: Gets stored in a file called product.liquid and the other is cart.liquid, but I can't store the users data on the site as they're anonymous and there would be no way of selecting the file they uploaded so it has to be from the HTML Local Storage of their session that carries it over.....

Comment: not sure what that means

Comment: window.onload = function() {
 var picture = localStorage.getItem('img');
 var image = document.createElement('img');
 image.src = picture;
 document.body.appendChild(image);
};

This is whats on the second page bringing the image through but its just displaying the image full size at the bottom of the page and I just want it like height: 100px width: 100px next to some text......

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry forgot to tag you

Comment: can also set the `src` of existing tag that is placed where you want it if that helps. Give image tag an ID and makes it easy to target

Comment: Any chance of demonstrating in here and sending me the link [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) ? @charlietfl

Comment: `$(#imageId').attr('src', picture)`

Comment: and where would I put that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832635/html-localstorage-css-issues/34832735#34832735 @charlietfl this works great... thanks for all your help before though!