# HTML localStorage CSS Issues?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Okay so I've successfully managed after a couple of hours to call over an image using HTML localStorage system but I now have one problem with the called over image.... I can't dictate where it goes..... It just sits at the bottom of the page as the code is purely javascript..... I've tried putting it in a div and changing its position but it won't budge any suggestions.... heres the code thats calling the image across:

```
    window.onload = function() {
 var picture = localStorage.getItem('img');
 var image = document.createElement('img');
 image.src = picture;
 document.body.appendChild(image);
};
```

How can I edit the position on the page as well as the hight etc......................? Any help appreciated!

Comment: _"tried putting it in a div and changing its position but it won't budge"_ What "position" on page, and `height` should image have ?

Comment: It displays at the bottom and i need it to be at the top half with height and width at about 100px ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're appending the image to the document body, so likewise, it's going to be added to the bottom of the page.

You can set the properties of `image.style` to change the image's CSS properties such as height (`image.style.height`) and width (`image.style.width`).

To position it elsewhere on the page, you can change it's display properties

```
image.style.position = "absolute"; //(for example)
image.style.top = "50px"; //drops the image down 50px from the top of the page
```

Or, you can add it to a different part of the DOM altogether:

```
document.getElementById('ID_OF_YOUR_DIV').appendChild(image);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you thats Worked! Just wondering..... My image gets squished when the hight and width is applied is there any way of overriding that? and also when i put a portrait image in it turns landscape? any way of changing that too?

Comment: If you set both height and width, and the height and width you set is not proportional to the size of the actual image, the image will appear squished. As for the portrait image turning landscape... I don't think I've seen that happen before without applying some rotation CSS on it. Are you sure it's saved in portrait orientation?

Comment: yeah is there any way of entering that and not viewing the excess image? and yep its saved as portrait :)

Comment: Just apply one measurement. The other should automatically size down to be proportional. Or you can use equal percentages for the height and width.

Comment: okay, is there any way of the code reading the image data and rotating it to be portrait too?

Comment: You could always rotate it 90 degrees: `image.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)"` if the top of the image is on the left side. Or if the top of the image is on the right side, rotate it 270 degrees.

Comment: but if I uploaded a landscape image that would then become portrait wouldn't it?

Comment: Just apply it to whatever image is having the problem (if that's an option). There's no way [that I know of in JavaScript or CSS] to automatically determine which images should be landscape and which should be portrait. I suggest going back and re-saving your images, just to make sure they're saved correctly.

Comment: its for a test shop so customers upload their images and the company prints them so technically theres no control over the images uploaded but its okay I've discover a few problems with this anyway so I may not use it anymore..... thanks for everything though! if i do use it i now know what to do!  :)